# How much I can expect at noise reduction in a apartment with high budget?

Tags: sound-proofing

This is the first time I'm dealing with this issue.

I live in a apartment with lots of Airbnbs, and such there is always noise of people changing floors, drills and stuff.

With a budget of 20.000 USD how much you can expect in noise reduction ? I was hoping for at least 60-80 dB

I am not worried about thickness. But at same time I don't want to have any unevenness between the floors. There is a Windows that will also be sound proofed.

Is it realistic to expect to be able to sleep and hear no noise of people doing construction in their homes?

If it helps I'm planning on getting a ceiling fan too so it will generate some room noise as well

Comment: Sound will travel through the floor. It is virtually impossible to isolate yourself from that.

Comment: I once rented from a beautiful old apartment. It was wood framed rather than concrete, and the neighbors above were up all hours of the day. The floors squeaked. So I  moved. That's the nice thing about apartments, relatively speaking.

Comment: I think you need determine how the noise is getting into your flat.  Through walls? ceiling? floor? windows/doors?

Comment: Budget is off-topic. $20k spent in the US will get you "X" amount of stuff, but $20k spent in another country will get you a very different amount of stuff. There's no way for us to know how much sound proofing $20k will get you in your country. It is _highly_ unlikely, though, that $20k will get you 60dB reduction in _any_ country. That's nearly anechoic chamber levels of noise reduction and that's _expensive_. I do find it amusing that you want to reduce noise levels that much, but then you're _adding_ the noise of a fan...

Comment: An 80dB reduction is asking for a lot - that's like having a jet engine outside your window, and not even noticing it over the ambient noise of your house.

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered with the limited information provided, and it's off topic for several reasons. Please see the [help].

Answer (score 1):

40DB is a quiet library. Lovest sound level comfortable to human is around 35DB. 35+60-80 is 95-115DB. It is nearby rock concert or starting jet level loudness. Drils and jackhamers are 60-110 but on site, even by wall it is 80DB max

20-40DB reduction can be get from carpets - on floor, walls and celling, if have them on then only sound source will be windows and doors, as long Your neighbour do not use jackhamer on Your wall.

If need more then need do  structural changes in construction like build a cage insulated by fiberglass or so and lined with special sound dampenig materials. But this is lots more than 20k USD to spend

Comment: I don't mind structural changes... in my country 20k USD is a lot. I'm pretty sure it will cover what you are thinking

Answer (score 0):

Sound transmission depends on frequency.

You can stop frequencies from 6kHz upwards with little more than some rockwool. The windows & walls themselves are very probably already doing this.

Anything below 100Hz though & you need mass and isolation [air-gapping].
What you're looking at is building an entire room within a room, isolated as much as possible from the existing structure. In an apartment block, this is impracticable. Even if you started with a room 30ft square with 14ft ceilings, it would be cheaper to move.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle one step as you enter/exit the apartment to get onto the new floating/isolated framed floor, it's possible to have no other unevenness to the floor, as the whole thing would be newly built, somewhat above the old floor, on vibration isolation mounts. New walls inside the old walls, new ceiling below the old ceiling, lots of rockwool and floating mounts on the other side. Perhaps some sand, or mass loaded vinyl as well.